# SSMS file tree does not match file tree on drive

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm trying to add a database to my SQL server using a .mdf file, but the filetree displayed by SSMS does not reflect the filetree on my C drive, so I cannot locate my .mdf file when I try to add the database. The folder just doesn't show up.

My .mdf file is inside a folder I've created on the C drive, which is not displayed when I'm browsing in SSMS. I've tried pretty much everything involving permissions and at this point have granted full permissions to every user, with no luck.

Any ideas on what could be the issue?

[File tree while browsing on SSMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLJ1T.png)

[File tree while browsing with Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYp4C.png)

Answer (score 1):

When restoring a database using SQL Server, the file path is relative to the server, not the machine on which you are running SSMS. You should copy the file to the server and browse for it using SSMS.

Note that the folder where you put the file must be accessible by the user account under which the SQL Server service is running.